# React native Android Picker not showing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

The `picker` itself its showing, but not its data. Also when I click on it it shows an empty, white label.

```
{/* Order by picker */}
<View style={globalStyles.rowView}>{/* FlexDirection:'row' */}
    <Text style={[globalStyles.text,styles.text]}>Ordenar por:</Text> {/* color:colors.white, fontSize:"17rem"*/}
    <Picker style={[globalStyles.text, styles.picker]}{/* color:colors.white, fontSize:"17rem"*/}{/* flex:1 */}
       selectedValue={this.state.orden}
       onValueChange={(itemIndex)=>{this.setState({orden:this.state.ordenar[itemIndex]})}}>

       {this.state.ordenar.map(element => {
           <Picker.Item label={element} value={element}/>
        })}

     </Picker>
</View>
```

When I try with

```
<Picker.Item label={this.state.orden} value={this.state.orden}/>
```

or with

```
<Picker.Item label={this.state.ordenar[1]} value={this.state.ordenar[1]}/>
```

they both work, so `this.state.orden` and `this.state.ordenar` aren't empty, and I imagine that is not a problem of styling or flexbox, as in this second way is showing the data, so I suppose that the problem is the `map` function

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which Picker-Component do you use? What do you mean with white-label (provide a screenshot) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `jsx` element from your map function in order for it to work.
Refer the code snippet below, I have updated your map function.

```
 {/* Order by picker */}
    <View style={globalStyles.rowView}>{/* FlexDirection:'row' */}
        <Text style={[globalStyles.text,styles.text]}>Ordenar por:</Text> {/* color:colors.white, fontSize:"17rem"*/}
        <Picker style={[globalStyles.text, styles.picker]}{/* color:colors.white, fontSize:"17rem"*/}{/* flex:1 */}
           selectedValue={this.state.orden}
           onValueChange={(itemIndex)=>{this.setState({orden:this.state.ordenar[itemIndex]})}}>

           {this.state.ordenar.map(element => {
               return(<Picker.Item label={element} value={element}/>) /*wrap your picker item around return.*/
            })}

         </Picker>
    </View>
```

Comment: I knew it had to be a silly thing like that. Tried and working. Thanks